# Correct exception to throw for an unhandled switch case for an argument?

Tags: c#, .net, exception

Say we have `SomeEnum` and have a switch statement handling it like:

```cs
enum SomeEnum
{
    One,
    Two,
}

void someFunc(SomeEnum value)
{
    switch(value)
    {
        case SomeEnum.One:
            ...
            break;
        case SomeEnum.Two:
            ... 
            break;
        default:
            throw new ??????Exception("Unhandled value: " + value.ToString());    
    }
}
```

As you see we handle all possible enum values but still keep a default throwing an exception in case a new member gets added and we want to make sure we are aware of the missing handling.

My question is: what's the right exception in such circumstances where you want to notify that the given code path is not handled/implemented or should have never been visited? We used to use `NotImplementedException` but it doesn't seem to be the right fit. Our next candidate is `InvalidOperationException` but the term doesn't sound right. What's the right one and why?

**EDIT**: C# 8.0 introduced [switch expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/switch-expression) which produce compiler warnings for non-exahustive switch statements. That's another reason why you should use switch expressions over switch statements whenever applicable. The same function can be written in a safer way like:

```cs
void someFunc(SomeEnum value)
{
    _ = value switch
    {
        SomeEnum.One => ....,
        SomeEnum.Two => ...., 
    }
}
```

When a new member gets added to `SomeEnum`, the compiler will show the warning *"CS8509: The switch expression does not handle all possible values of its input type (it is not exhaustive). For example, the pattern 'EnumHandling.SomeEnum.Three' is not covered."* for the switch expression which makes it way easier to catch potential bugs.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I'd throw the [`InvalidEnumArgumentException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.invalidenumargumentexception.aspx) as it will give more detailed information in this case, you are checking on an enum

Comment: As the difference might easily be overread, I'd exceptionally like to point out how this answer is probably a better solution than the other answers that point to the (more generic, less specific) `ArgumentException`.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Thanks I agree, the more specific you can be the more detailed information you can derive from the exception

Comment: @O.R.Mapper I agree but the question was closed. Since now it's open again, I picked this as the accepted answer. Thanks @CR41G14!

Answer (score 23):

`ArgumentException` looks the most correct to me in this instance (though is not defined in the BCL).

There is a specialized exception for enum arguments - [InvalidEnumArgumentException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.invalidenumargumentexception.aspx):

> The exception thrown when using invalid arguments that are enumerators.

An alternative is [ArgumentOutOfRangeException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.argumentoutofrangeexception.aspx):

> The exception that is thrown when the value of an argument is outside the allowable range of values as defined by the invoked method.

The logic for using these is that the passed in argument (`value`) is not valid as far as `someFunc` is concerned.

Comment: You mean [`ArgumentException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.argumentexception.aspx)? [`InvalidArgumentException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.common.invalidargumentexception.aspx) is for Sql-Server.

Comment: InvalidArgumentException is in the Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common namespace and hardly appropriate for the general case - especially since it derives from ConnectionException

Comment: Why not `InvalidEnumArgumentException`?

Comment: @TimSchmelter - No. Several other libraries do define `InvalidArgumentException` (which semantically may be the most correct here). For instance SMO defines it, MS Office libraries also define it.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper - Good one. Didn't think of that one... thanks.

Comment: @Oded: Someone else thought of it first - see the respective answer below.

Comment: "There is a specialized version for enums - InvalidEnumArgumentException:" - InvalidEnumArgumentException is not a specialized version of (derived from) InvalidArgumentException.

Comment: This is ok for parameter validation but is it the right exception when it's not a parameter but a return value from another function call? I'll edit question to broaden it's scope.

Comment: @ssg: I think you should ask another question for that, because IMO it has another answer.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper: I didn't think two cases would have two different answers. Should I revert my edit and create a new one?

Comment: @ssg: With respect to future readers and general SO guidelines, I'd be in favour of that: My answer to your first question (argument) would definitely be `InvalidEnumArgumentException`, whereas my answer to the other question (internal value) would definitely be `InvalidOperationException`.

Comment: @ssg - It would definitely have a different answer.

Comment: @ssg: The point/reason being that with an argument, the one who is first confronted with the exception (the calling code) did something wrong (pass an invalid argument value), whereas with an internal return value, the calling code is seldom guilty of the problem and can at most try to deal with the situation gracefully, but not prevent the problem.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper: it makes sense, asked the other question.

Comment: Apparently [`ArgumentOutOfRangeException` is used by some](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.argumentoutofrangeexception?view=net-7.0), but this strikes me as odd. The only indication in the documentation this may be relevant is: _"contains an invalid value that is not a member of **the set of values** expected for the argument"_. But, (1) if that's the criteria, then essentially any `ArgumentException` could be considered a range exception, making the type meaningless; and (2) "range" in the type name implies _comparable_ values, which enums semantically aren't.

Answer (score 4):

Since you have the login in a function you can throw [InvalidArgumentException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.common.invalidargumentexception.aspx).

> The exception that is raised **when a parameter that is not valid is
>   passed to a method** on the referenced connection to the server.

**EDIT:**
A better alternative would be: [ArgumentException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.argumentexception.aspx), since `InvalidArgumentException` in `Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common` namespace. Something like:

```
throw new ArgumentException("Unhandled value: " + value.ToString());
```

Comment: InvalidArgumentException is in the Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common namespace and hardly appropriate for the general case - especially since it derives from ConnectionException

Comment: @Joe, thanks for that, I was editing my answer after seeing your comment earlier

Answer (score 0):

InvalidArgumentException. 
when user pass some invalid value or null value when value value is required, it is recommended to handle InvalidArgumentException .

Answer (score 0):

If you were using Code Contracts (something I *HIGHLY* recommend), you would put this at the start of the method:

```
Contract.Requires(value == SomeEnum.One || value == SomeEnum.Two);
```

If you want to check a range of an enum which has too many individual values to write them all explicitly, you can do it like this:

```
Contract.Requires(SomeEnum.One <= value && value <= SomeEnum.Two);
```

Comment: The OP specifically points to the case where the input value *is* defined, but is not handled by the method.

Answer (score 0):

Exceptions are part of the **contract of the interface**, so it all depends on what you want to communicate; what is the *intent*. I can think of three different scenarios:

1. The unhandled case is an *implementation error*, i.e., it should be considered a bug and never occur.
2. There is no intent to ever support this case.
3. The unhandled case could work in practice, but is *currently not supported*.

In the first two cases, an ideal API would *prevent* the exception from ever occurring. In the third case, an exception may be preferred as a way to maintain a clearer API which can evolve more easily.

Considering the three scenarios in more detail:

1. [`NotImplementedException`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.notimplementedexception?view=net-7.0) communicates this well. But, this is not something you would commit to a stable branch or want to see in production code. And, as a general rule of thumb, wherever language features can help you to avoid writing exceptions, use them. As the OP points out in an edit, [C# 8.0's switch expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/switch-expression) serve the same purpose. Instead of a runtime error, you will get a compilation error.
2. I personally prefer an [`ArgumentException`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.argumentexception?view=net-7.0). But, I would also consider whether I could prevent the exception by embedding the same information in the type system. For example, remove the enum value, or create a purpose-limited enum which is a subset of the original enum.
3. [`NotSupportedException`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.notsupportedexception?view=net-7.0) is often used for more abstract interfaces, but you are (not yet) prepared to provide an implementation for all the concrete cases. Note that this should be considered a violation of the [Liskov Substitution Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle); however, if there is an *intent* to support an implementation in the future, this may be a worthwhile tradeoff.

As a concluding note, apparently some people use [`ArgumentOutOfRangeException`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.argumentoutofrangeexception?view=net-7.0), also mentioned [by one of the existing answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13644755/590790). But, [this strikes me as odd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13644737/correct-exception-to-throw-for-an-unhandled-switch-case-for-an-argument#comment136160981_13644755):

> The only indication in the documentation this may be relevant is: *"contains an invalid value that is not a member of **the set of values** expected for the argument"*. But, (1) if that's the criteria, then essentially any `ArgumentException` could be considered a range exception, making the type meaningless; and (2) "range" in the type name implies *comparable* values, which enums semantically aren't.